# Application 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' was recycled after detecting app_offline.htm - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I am working on a .NET project that I publish on Microsoft Azure.
When I publish the app, I see some termination in log files. In particular, the first one is:

`Application 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' was recycled after detecting app_offline.htm.`

I have no `app_offline.htm` in my directory in Visual Studio.
So I am publishing the application, and it immediately terminates, hence stops working.

How do I fix this?

Comment: How are you deploying the application? From Visual Studio, or are you using a pipeline?

Comment: @rickvdbosch I am publishing it from Visual Studio using the publishing profile I've downloaded from my Azure Project

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `.csproj` in Visual Studio, because it probably holds the setting you're looking for. One of the properties you can set for Web Deploy (MSDeploy) is `EnableMSDeployAppOffline`, which seems to default to `true`.

[image: .csproj contents]

This is causing the `app_offline.htm` file to be created. Set the `EnableMsDeployAppOffline` value to `false` if you don't want to take the app offline when publishing.

Also, taken from [Visual Studio publish profiles (.pubxml) for ASP.NET Core app deployment - Compute project items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-6.0#compute-project-items).

> When an ASP.NET Core project references `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` in the project file, an *app_offline.htm* file is placed at the root of the web app directory. When the file is present, the ASP.NET Core Module gracefully shuts down the app and serves the *app_offline.htm* file during the deployment.

Comment: I have added this line to my .csproj file (but with `False`) and published, but the error is the same =/
Any ideas?

Comment: You should of course, set the `EnableMsDeployAppOffline` value to `false` if you don't want to take the app offline when publishing.

Comment: And also, I don't see `app_offline.htm` in Azure files either. Where is it?

Comment: Yet another thing, when I start the service manually in Azure, it doesn't work either, with the same error. Something is going on...

Comment: Some deployment tools also create that file, e.g. [Azure DevOps task iisweb-app-deployment-on-machine-group-v0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/iisweb-app-deployment-on-machine-group-v0?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) has got `TakeAppOfflineFlag` which defaults to `false`, but my project has had it inherited with value `true`.